# Data mismatch and compiler cannot deduce template argument

Tags: c++, templates, max, parameter-passing, min

I have this template function for max

```
template <typename T>
T max(T a, T b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }
```

And I wanted to replace these:

```
int max(int a, int b){ return (a > b) ? a : b; }
char cmax(char a, char b){ return (a > b) ? a : b; }  
unsigned int umax(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){ return (a > b) ? a : b; }
```

I need `a` and `b` to have the same type.
But my code (which I am porting from C to C++) has things like this:

```
size_t myvar;
...
...
int i = max(myvar,5);
```

VS2015 output:

```
Error   C2672   'max': no matching overloaded function found    
Error   C2672   'max': no matching overloaded function found
Error   C2782   'T max(T,T)': template parameter 'T' is ambiguous
Error   C2784   'T max(T,T)': could not deduce template argument for 'T' from 'int'
```

Okay, I should probably cast `5` to `size_t`.

My question is the following: why C allows this? And more importantly, what happens under the hood? Does the compiler casts 5 to size_t or what? What can be the consequences of this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Note that your C version has other failure cases, that may not generate a compilation warning, e.g. when the input is larger than `INT_MAX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C code where you're calling `max`, both arguments are implicitly converted to type `int`, since the function's parameters have type `int`. So `myvar` is converted to `int` (it is not `5` that is converted to `size_t`). The conversion from `size_t` to `int` should be avoided since it is often narrowing (`size_t` is often longer than `int`).

In C++14, you can write a `max` template that can take two arguments of different types as follows:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto max(T a, U b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

In C++11, the solution is slightly more verbose:

```
template <class T, class U>
typename std::common_type<T, U>::type max(T a, U b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

The return type will be whatever type the ternary expression has. For two integer types of different sizes, the longer type will be chosen, so no information will be lost. (Some information may be lost if one type is signed and the other is unsigned and both have the same length.)

Comment: I thought about doing your first solution. Both your solutions work, although the compiler warns about unsigned/signed (size_t/int) mismatch. Thanks for the explanation!